# PostGIS ST_ConvexHull() but perpendicular to a line?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a rather special requirement for a PostGIS geometry manipulation.

Consider the following case:

[image]

I have a polygon and a line feature. If I do a `ST_ConvexHull()` or `ST_ConcaveHull()` I would get something like on the left side. However, what I need is the area that encloses the polygon and the line where its perpendicular lines touch the polygon. Is there a function or another multiple step way to achieve this in PostGIS?

I think with `ST_ShortestLine()` from each vertex of the polygon to the line it may be possible. However, I still don't know, how I can get the area from the set of shortest lines.

Comment: Given your line is always horizontal as in your example, just take the min/max x and max y from the bbox of the polygon, plus the overall y from the line, and build a new polygon.

Comment: And if the line is not horizontal, it should be possible to rotate it and the polygon to make it horizontal, compute the area, and rotate that back.

Comment: @geozelot Even with the min/max X It still seems quite fiddly to "build a new polygon".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @dr_jts done. Specific case handling only, but not as clumsy as you may think. And fast. I added my preferred generic solution as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK. I figured it out myself. By doing a `ST_ShortestLine()` on each vertex of the polygon and then a `ST_Convexhull()` on this set of lines and a final `ST_Difference()` between that area and the area of the polygon I will get what I need.

Answer (score 4):

In the specific case (i.e. your example) where

- the line follows the `Y` axis
- the opposite (topmost) polygon border equals the (topmost) bounding box segment

you can simply extent the polygon bbox to get the desired area:

```
SELECT ST_MakeBox2D(
        ST_MakePoint(ST_XMin(ply.box), ST_YMin(ln.box)),
        ST_MakePoint(ST_XMax(ply.box), ST_YMax(ply.box))
       )::GEOMETRY(POLYGON) AS geom
FROM   (
    SELECT ply.geom::BOX2D AS box
    FROM   <polygon>
) AS ply, (
    SELECT ln.geom::BOX2D AS box
    FROM   <line>
) AS ln
;
```

This allows for input set relations (creating this area for closest pair of geomertries only etc.) and adjustments to the resulting area.

---

In all other cases it would likely be more efficient to simply dump all polygon vertices, get their projection on the line, and create the convex hull from the point set directly - either

- by pre-collecting pairs:

  ```
  SELECT ST_ConvexHull(
           ST_Collect(geom)
         ) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT ST_Collect(
             dmp.geom,
             ST_LineinterpolatePoint(
               ln.geom,
               ST_LineLocatePoint(
                 ln.geom,
                 dmp.geom
               )
             )
           ) AS geom
    FROM   <polygon> AS ply,
           <line> AS ln,
           LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(ply.geom) AS dmp
  ) q
  ;
  ```
- or a simple `UNION` of all individual points:

  ```
  WITH
    pts AS (
      SELECT dmp.geom
      FROM   ply,
             LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS dmp
    )
  SELECT ST_ConvexHull(
           ST_Collect(geom)
         ) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT geom
    FROM   pts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ST_LineinterpolatePoint(
             ln.geom,
             ST_LineLocatePoint(
               ln.geom,
               pts.geom
             )
           ) AS geom
    FROM   ln, pts
  ) q
  ;
  ```

I'd prefer the former, except for when there is already a list of CTEs.

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation.

So, if your shapes do have vertical lines perpendicular to the horizontal line, as shown in your illustration,

run the script:

```
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM polygon) a JOIN line b ON true),
tblb AS (SELECT geom, ST_Length(geom) length FROM tbla GROUP BY geom ORDER BY length DESC LIMIT 2)
SELECT ST_PointsInStarPolygon(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM
        (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM tblb) a) b;
```

In addition to the basic functions, don't forget about the existence of custom functions, such as: ST_PointsInStarPolygon(https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/350004/120129) - developed by Martin Davis - (user:14766).

Original spatial solutions :-)...

Update

dr-jts, this is how new simple custom spatial functions written in GEO SQL are born :-),

I won't let good geo-tools written in SQL programming language go to waste :-)...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_SnapPolygonToLine(
    geom1 GEOMETRY,
    geom2 GEOMETRY)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS  
$BODY$
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump($1)).geom),
tblb AS (SELECT (ST_Dump($2)).geom),
tblc AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM tbla) a JOIN tblb b ON true)
SELECT ST_PointsInStarPolygon(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM
        (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM tblc) a) b;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

RUN

`SELECT ST_SnapPolygonToLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM polygon a JOIN line b ON true`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of another solution:

1. For each vertex in the polygon shell, use `ST_LineLocatePoint` to find its fractional index along the line.
2. Construct the line segments from each vertex to the line, and pick the shortest ones with max and min index
3. Construct the subline along the baseline between the max and min indices
4. Extract all the line segments from the polygon
5. Polygonize the extracted and constructed line segments. This should produce two polygons
6. Union the polygonization results

This is going to be complex to implement in SQL.  A function might be a better way to implement this.